# Angular Material Form Fields Not Behaving Properly

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have been following a [boilerplate template](https://github.com/sebastienlevert/spfx-ng-webparts/tree/master/spfx-ng-material) for using an Angular Element component in a SharePoint Framework webpart. With this template being used and the following package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/elements": "angular/elements-builds#labs/elements",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.11",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.3.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.3.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.3.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.3.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "chance": "^1.0.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  }
```

The form fields behave as normal (placeholders bounce up, label and underline change colors, etc). 
[image: Material Behavior Angular 5] 
When I updated the project to Angular 6, made the changes to register the custom component using the new syntax, I get a functioning form, but with the following behavior:

[image: Material Behavior Angular 6]

package.json post upgrade:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/elements": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.3",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.3.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.3.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.3.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.3.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "chance": "^1.0.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  }
```

The only other thing I can detect that differs between the two is the event listeners on the input fields. The working field has event listeners from zone.js: [image: Working]

The non-working fields event listeners on the input is from platform-browser: 
[image: Platform]

Is there any chance anyone might have suggestions on what needs to be configured to properly get Angular Material functioning as designed?

Comment: Version mismatch: ` "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",` If you want to use Angular 6 you need to use the corresponding Angular - Material package

Comment: @Z.Bagley Perhaps my formatting could be better on the post. The ^5.0.0-rc.2 angular material is in the package.json that corresponds to the top image where the functionality works. There is a package.json below the gif of the non functioning form which shows an updated angular material.

Comment: All I can think is that you're not wrapping it inside a `mat-form-field` which is now _required_ when before it was optional. If it isn't that, then it has to be with the module not being properly imported. Most likely not nested correct: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Comment: Forgot you were using some 3rd party library, which in that case _their_ library may not be nested correctly.

Comment: You need to import an angular material theme first in your `styles.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a theme in your `styles.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Comment: initially thought that could be the issue, but if I manually edit the element in a debugger and add the mat-focused class to the form field element, the field properly displays with the placeholder moving up, and the colors being applied.